# Drop down menu <li> hover changing background image

Tags: css, menu, background, hover, html-lists

I have a drop down menu and I'd like each main menu tab to change to a specific image while hovering over it with the mouse.

```
ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;}
li ul {display: none;}
ul li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #fff;}
ul li a:hover {}
li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
li:hover li {float: none;}
li:hover a {background-image:url(rf3.gif);}
li:hover li a:hover {background: #fec96b; color:#fff;}

<ul>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like tabs like 'Support' and 'Web Desing' to change to **each of their unique images** - they are different.

I tried adding a class to ex.

```
<li class="hover"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
```

but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give those two list items a unique class name, and then specify the appropriate CSS for them.

CSS:

```
ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;}
li ul {display: none;}
ul li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #fff;}
ul li a:hover {}
li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
li:hover li {float: none;}
li:hover a {background-image:url(rf3.gif);}
li:hover li a:hover {background: #fec96b; color:#fff;}
li.support > a:hover { background-url(path_to_image_for_support.png); }
li.web-design > a:hover { background-url(path_to_image_for_web_design.png); }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="support"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<li class="web-design"><a href="#">Web Design</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: well i got a problem: for 'Web design' when the menu expands the whole row has a same repeating background..

Comment: Use the direct descendant selector ( > ).  I've updated the last two lines in the CSS sectio of my answer accordingly.  The CSS should then only apply to a-elements which are direct descendands of the li's with the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript. Instead of class, use 'ID' and assign each one a number. Then create a Javscript function that will use:

```
document.getElementById('[line number]').style.backgroundColor = "[desired background color]";
```

Done.

Comment: Why on earth use javascript for a presentational change?  This is exactly what CSS is meant for!